# Working with Trisection Search Tree in Python

Tags: python, recursion, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to search a node from the following Trisection Tree each node has three children's (must use **Recursion**)

```
                        (1,5)
                      /0  |1  \2
                     /    |    \                   
                (2,7)          (1,3)
              /0  |1 \2      /0 |1 \2
                  |   \         |   \
                     (7,5)          (0,-5)
                  

key=(1,5), children=[key=(2,7), children=[None, None, key=(7,5), children=[None, None, None]], None, key=(1,3), children=[None, None, key=(0,-5), children=[None, None, None]]]
```

Here is my search function contain argument p (p is a node which I want to search e.g. (1,3))

```
def search(self,p):
        
        if self.key == None:
            return None
        if p == self.key:
            return self
        elif self.child[0]:
                            
            if self.child[0] == None:
                return None
            else:
                return self.child[0].search(p)
        elif self.child[1]:
                            
            if self.child[1] == None:
                return None
            else:
                return self.child[1].search(p)
        elif self.child[2]:
                           
            if self.child[2] == None:
                return None
            else:
                return self.child[2].search(p)
```

Output can be if p=(1,3)

```
key=(1,3), children=[None, None, key=(0,-5), children=[None, None, None]]
```

How to do this..

Comment: What is the difference between what you *want* this code to do and what it *actually* does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the issues:

- If you enter the `elif self.child[0]` block, then the next (nested) `if` condition (`self.child[0] == None`) is always going to be false.
- In that same block there will always be a `return` that executes, i.e. no other child will ever be checked.

Not the problem, but:

- The `self.key == None` condition seems to assume that... there could be a `None` key, which makes me think your Tree class is always having at least one node, and that you indicate an empty tree with a `None` key. That is not the best practice. An empty tree should just have *no* nodes at all. So you should separate a Node class from a Tree class, where the Tree class has a root attribute that is either None (empty tree) or a Node instance.

Here is the correction of your method:

```
    def search(self, p):
        if p == self.key:
            return self
        for child in self.child:
            found = child and child.search(p)
            if found:
                return found
```

Comment: Hy, can you please tell me how to find the depth of this tree given in post ?

Comment: You can use recursion. If the node has no children, the depth is 0 (or 1, depending on how you define "depth"). If it has children, get the depth (recursively) of each child, and add 1 to the maximum you get from that.

Comment: Can you please do it.. I don't understand how to iterate every child...

Comment: If you can't get it to work, then please ask a new question, and show your code, and what is wrong with what it does. BTW, in my answer here, the code iterates the children, so that should not be a problem.